# How to offset twinx y-axis by specified amount?

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis, twinx

I am familiar to using `twinx()` to share an axis's x-axis with another subplot:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(xdata1, ydata1)
ax2.plot(xdata2, ydata2)
```

This makes the `y=0` axis line up between `ax1` and `ax2`, but the axes are still on separate subplots so they each get their own autoscaling to match whatever is plotted on them as normal.  However, I have a situation where I need to create separate axes `ax1` and `ax2` on the different subplots, but with a specified offset between their x-axes - i.e. `ax1`'s `y=y0` needs to line up with `ax2`'s `y=0`, for some nonzero offset `y0`, like this:

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61596813/3845439) appears to be close to what I am after, but not quite the same.  That example uses a secondary y-axis with a function relating its values to the primary y-axis.  However, I need a separate subplot entirely with its own scaling just like `twinx()` gives me.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to create a new subplot manually and set its position relative to the first subplot. Then you can share the x axis via `ax.sharex(...)` and you're good to go

This should do the job:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 1000)
ydata1 = np.exp(x/10)
ydata2 = np.sin(x)


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot() # create a new subplot
pos = list(ax1.get_position().bounds) # get the position of the first subplot
pos[1] += 0.15  # shift the y-position of the subplot... pos = (x0, y0, width, height)
ax2.set_position(pos) # set the new position
ax2.sharex(ax1)       # share x axis with first subplot
ax2.patch.set_visible(False) # hide the background patch
ax2.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, # put ticks and labels on the right axis
                right=True, labelright=True)

ax1.plot(x, ydata1, "r-")
ax2.plot(x, ydata2, "b-")
```